# EPEL & Codeready-builder AWS EC2 RHEL8

Tags: r, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I am running an EC2 instance with a RHEL8 AMI.

I am looking to install R on the instance and I believe I need the EPEL package and to enable the codeready builder through the following two commands

```
sudo dnf install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled rhui-codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-rhui-rpms
```

more info at (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/)

I can download epel (first line) fine but when I run the second line I get the following:

```
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Error: No matching repo to modify: rhui-codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-rhui-rpms.
```

Also when I try to run the following, I get the following:

```
This system has no repositories available through subscriptions.
```

and for completeness, this is the error when i try to install R

```
$sudo yum install -y R

This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:52:36 ago on Mon 04 May 2020 01:17:58 AM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: package R-3.6.3-1.el8.x86_64 requires R-devel = 3.6.3-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package R-devel-3.6.3-1.el8.x86_64 requires R-core-devel = 3.6.3-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides openblas-devel needed by R-core-devel-3.6.3-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides texinfo-tex needed by R-core-devel-3.6.3-1.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Does anyone have any ideas or has solved this same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked this out just after writing it...

For anyones reference, it seems AWS had their command written wrongly.

Still download epel package as shown above

sudo dnf install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

and instead of the following from AWS website

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled rhui-codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-rhui-rpms
```

You can use

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-rhui-rpms
```

Then go ahead with sudo yum install -y R